# Вопрос про EOF в cmd

Tags: c

Есть программа из K&R

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int get_line(char *line, int max);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int found = 0;
    if (argc != 2)
        printf("Please use example in FIND\n");
    else
        while (get_line(line, MAXLINE) > 0)
            if (strstr(line, argv[1]) != NULL)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", line);
                    found++;
                }
    return found;
}

int get_line(char *s, int max)
{
    int c;
    int len = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && (len < MAXLINE - 1) && (c != '\n'))
        {
            *s++ = c;
            len++;
        }
    if (c = '\n')
        {
            *s = '\0';
        }
    return len;
}
```

Программа работает, всё замечательно. Я ввожу в командную строку некое стихотворение, программа отрабатывает, нажимаю Ctrl-Z, программа прекращает выполнение.

Теперь, допустим, я хочу получить полную длину строки (то есть считающую в том числе и `'\0'` в конце строки. Модифицирую get_line следующим образом

```
if (c = '\n')
    {
       *s = '\0';
       len++;
    }
```

В итоге после того, как программа отработала, я нажимаю Сtrl-Z, но программа свою работу не завершает. То есть получается, что Windows видит сначала символ `^` и только потом обрабатывает EOF (`^Z`) полностью, поэтому `len` всегда больше нуля, я правильно понимаю?

И второй вопрос, как принудительно завершить программу в случае вот таких бесконечных циклов, не закрывая терминала (работаю в Visual Studio Code)?

Comment: При нажатии Ctrl-C / Ctrl-Z и еще кучи других комбинаций клавиш никакого ввода в терминал не происходит, а происходит отправка **сигнала** процессу, в который смотрит в этот терминал

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (c = '\n')
> ```

```
if (c == '\n')
```

Отладчик надо использовать, раз уж не замечаешь такие ошибки.

К тому же, этот if вообще не нужен.

Comment: Действительно, спасибо. Ну а принудительное "убийство" программы если уж это произошло?

Comment: Программу завершает Ctrl+C, а не Ctrl+Z.

Comment: Странный ответ тем более для вопроса, требующего закрытия по факту.

Comment: @alexolut, не вижу причин для закрытия.

Comment: Полно: 1. два вопроса в одном; 2. вызвано опечаткой; 3. нет mcve. Ну хоть про сам ответ возражений не последовало :-D

Comment: @alexolut, они подразумевались))